# JavaScript line not executing - clearing the Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```
var imageCanvas = document.getElementById("imageCanvas");
var imageContext = imageCanvas.getContext("2d");
var board = new Image();
board.onload = function() {
    imageContext.drawImage(board, 0, 0, 400, 400);
};
board.src = "image/board.png";

imageContext.clearRect(0, 0, imageCanvas.width, imageCanvas.height);
```

So here is the code that I have. I loaded an image by its path and started testing how the canvas clears with the clearRect() function. The canvas does not clear with this command. But if I were to put a line of alert before the line where clearRect() is used, the canvas would be cleared successfully.

```
var imageCanvas = document.getElementById("imageCanvas");
var imageContext = imageCanvas.getContext("2d");
var board = new Image();
board.onload = function() {
    imageContext.drawImage(board, 0, 0, 400, 400);
};
board.src = "image/board.png";

alert(imageCanvas.width + " " + imageCanvas.height);
imageContext.clearRect(0, 0, imageCanvas.width, imageCanvas.height);
```

The second fragment of code works - it clears the canvas after I hit okay on the alert window. Does anyone understand why it behaves this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is racing against itself. `board.onload` will be executed when the image loads. It doesn't happen in the order the code runs, it is "asynchronous" and it's scheduled to run at a later time (when the image loads).

When you add the alert, you're giving time for the image to load. The alert itself has nothing to do with the behavior, it's just a delay. In your first code block, you clear the board, then the image load will get fired some time later, and draw the image.

Why do you want to load an image and then immediately clear the board? You could just remove the `.onload` function if you want to start with a clear board.

Comment: I see. I was building the code incrementally and wanted to test the functionality to clear the canvas first. Thank you for the input.